# What are the most interesting phenomena we will have in a universe where the speed of light is very slow or much faster?

Tags: universe

Let's say we have cloned our universe and created the Slow-Universe and the Fast-Universe.

Everything is the same except that:

- In the Slow-Universe, the speed of light is the same as the speed of sound.
- In the Fast-Universe, the speed of light is 10X faster than the original speed of light.

What interesting phenomenons we will encounter in these universes?

For example, in the slow-universe, communication via phone/email/... will be much much slower as information in communication cable will run so slow.

Comment: What is interesting is a matter of opinion. One of my professor at university used to go around and take pictures of rusting iron.

Comment: One of the most noticable phenomenon would be inexistance of a "classical" materials, stars and so on. Chemistry and, say, star structure are defined by speed of light. So it would be very dificult to imagine any phenomena in such a universes.

Comment: The problem is that the speed of light is intrinsically linked to the strength of electromagnetic forces, because $c = 1 / \sqrt{\varepsilon_0 \mu_0}$. If the speed of light is different then immediately the entire chemistry is different. I would say that a completely different chemistry is way more interesting than slow e-mail. If the speed of light is *radically* different (as the question asks, 1000 times slower) then just about *everything* will be different. There won't be any stars as we know them, for instance.

Comment: Might look at *Redshift Rendezvous* by John E. Stith for some well thought out visit to a more extreme "slow light" condition.

Comment: If light is mach1, would the speed of sound become 0.00039243504 m/s?

Comment: @Ceramicmrno0b: "Mach 1" is by definition the speed of sound in a given medium. If light is a thousand times slower than in our universe, the most important question is *the speed of sound in what*, because there would be no oxygen or nitrogen molecules, and most likely no oxygen or nitrogen atoms. (Because electromagnetic forces, such as those binding electrons to atomic nuclei, would also be a thousand times weaker.)

Comment: @AlexP, mainly i mean, if light is 874030 times slower, is everything else also 874030 time slower? if not, then a fighter jet from the slow universe could easily get up to several times the speed of light. we don't have anything that goes at ftl speeds, so who knows what this would look like.

Comment: VTC Needs focus. What, exactly, are you asking? Are all other laws of physics magically unaffected? The Q is too broad if not. Also, one question per-post, please. Finally, the speed of light is about 300,000 km/s. Reduce that by a factor of 874,030 (are you sure that's right?) and you get 343 m/s. If we're only talking about optical effects (magic exists), then you'd never be capable of tracking a bullet in flight - the light can't reflect fast enough.

Comment: Makes me think of DiscWorld.  The speed of light was slower there.

Comment: @Vaccano Diskworld also ran on *Narrativum*

Comment: @Ceramicmrno0b  No, if light is 874030 times slower, not everything would be 874030 times slower.  A fighter jet from the slow universe could definitely not exceed the speed of light, no matter how much slower the speed of light is.  If the speed of light is walking speed, then nothing in the universe can exceed walking speed.

Comment: @Trish - Very true!

Comment: @cowlinator that's an interesting question, though. Is there something intrinsic with light that limits everything else, or is there some law light is obeying and it's that law that limits everything else? Could a fictional universe "unhook" light from that law such that FTL was possible (even though it becomes trivial)? We use "c" to represent the limit, but if it's only a convenient representation, there could be a really cool question here.

Comment: @JBH, if the theory of General Relativity holds true, then there something intrinsic with the speed of light that limits everything else.  If General Relativity is false in that universe, then... I can make no predictions about what that would entail without a replacement theory.

Comment: This question has been asked a thousand times already. I don't want to check, but I've almost certainly answered it at least twice already. Alex already said basically everything, but anyhow, ignore everyone. Don't do this. If you don't know advanced physics, you will crash and burn with this. It's like trying to write a book in Japanese if all you know is an anime you watched in English. It's not a skill you have, I'm sorry. You either know the answer or you don't even try unless you're attempting comedy. In that case, whatever is funny works